# I got a syntax error during migration, functions Python3 to python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, migrating

```
def create_msg(content: bytes) -> bytes:
size = len(content)
return encode_msg_size(size) + content


def encode_msg_size(size: int) -> bytes:
return struct.pack("<I", size)
```

I want to migrate this two functions from python3 to python2.7 but i got everytime a syntax error.
Does somebody has any idea?

Error:
`File "__init__.py", line 4 def create_msg(content: bytes) -> bytes: SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Python 2's end of life was January 1, 2020 so it's best to stick to Python 3. Check your indents.

Comment: Please, show your python2 code and full traceback you get. And why migrate back to python2?

Comment: Why the [**downgrade**](https://endoflife.date/python)?

Comment: I know, but I have a lot of code right now in Python2.7 and only want to add these two functions for now :)

Comment: @Mr.JimFPV, please [edit] your question instead of trying to put code into comments.

Comment: Please show the python2 code, correctly formatted, and a full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function Annotations were introduced in python 3 [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).
remove annotations from your code:

```
def create_msg(content):
    size = len(content)
    return encode_msg_size(size) + content

def encode_msg_size(size):
    return struct.pack("<I", size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your error

Btw Your indents are wrong

Corrected indents and code :-.  (Not tested)

```
def create_msg(content):
    size = len(content)
    return bytes(encode_msg_size(size) + content)


def encode_msg_size(size):
    return bytes(struct.pack("<I", size))
```

that `content : bytes` format is not available in python 2